# Right aligning all page numbers in overleaf bibliography footer and appendix

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, alignment, appendices, footer

I have to as part of my thesis guidelines have this line at the bottom of every page "A.N.Other, PhD Thesis, Random University 2021" except on the title page and my page numbers all need to be on the right. I noticed some of my pages do this and others don't like the first page of my appendix and bibliography don't but the 2nd page does. Is there a way to do this so all pages have this like I'm supposed to? I have put my entire preamble below.
[image: What I now see after making changes-corrected by moving a figure that was too long onto the next page]
[image: What i want to see]
[image: What i see on some pages]
[image: Results page i want to have but has a blank page after]
[image: How my main matter appears with my sections]
I used this below to create it in chapter 3

```latex
    \begingroup%
    \makeatletter%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \let\newpage\relax%
    \let\clearpage\relax%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \vspace*{\dimexpr-50\p@-\baselineskip}% Remove the initial
    %% -default- 50pt gap (plus 1 line) 
    \section*{\huge \Centering Results}
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \endgroup%
\chapter{Bar}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Methods}
```

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}<--- set before fancydr otherwise footer will not be in the bottom right corner but more central and right
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % <---! added LE
\fancyfoot[CF]{A.N.Other, PhD Thesis, Random University 2025.}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % <---! overwrite the plain style with fancy
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%







\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}


% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% You need to edit the details here
% -------------------------------------------------------------------


\end{titlepage}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Declaration
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
\section*{\Large Declaration}





% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Abstract and Acknowledgements
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
abstract
Acknowledgements







% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Main sections (as required)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter
Chapter 1
sections/Chapter 2
sections/Chapter 3
sections/Chapter 4
sections/Chapter 5
sections/discussion



% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
% -------------------------------------------------------------------

\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{mybibliography} 


% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Appendices
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
\appendix
\begin{appendices}
\input{sections/appendix.tex}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Since your code inputs many files, we can't compile it. Would be better to provide a Minimal Working Exame which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @lukeflo I have made a more simplified if this helps?

Comment: Maybe not so much, because you deleted the code markers and the reference links to your pictures. Furthermore, you still input files with `input{xyz.tex}` which nobody has access to, so it still wont compile. At best, create a MWE with just dummy text and the particular sections, *without* inputting any file.

Comment: @lukeflo sorry I didn't mean to delete those files. Is this any better? I'm sorry if it's not i'm not too famililar with how MWE should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `book` class, you have twosided output. Thus, you have to define the pagenumber for odd (`R`) **and** even (`L`) pages: change the line `\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}` to `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}`. The `LE` makes the difference!

Furthermore, new chapters explicitly call `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Therefore, you have to add the line `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` to your praeambel to apply the `fancy` pagestyle to `plain` pages too.

Only the praeambel of your MWE now looks like that:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % <---! added LE
\fancyfoot[CF]{Anon.ther.name, PhD Thesis, university 2025.}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % <---! overwrite the plain style with fancy
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\begin{document}
```

For me, that does it with your code. Only the titlepage is left blank, since it uses `\thispagestyle{empty}` which stays untouched.

PS: I couldn't test the output for your bibliography. You didn't provide a `.bib`-file and so i commented the section out. But I guess it will work for this part too.

**Edit**: If I adapt the code from one of your input-chapters and place it in the main file, I get a result page with correct footer and on the following page chapter **Bar**. And the same result without blank page if I create a extra .tex document with your code snippet and `\input` it like you do in your `main.tex` file:

[image: result page]

Comment: Thank you this has worked for me, I used oneside not twoside but it still worked. I now have a weird blank page between my results title page and chapter 3. Before chapter 3 i want a results page, then after that it is a blank page and then chapter 3 starts. How do i remove this and make sure the chapter starts on the chapter 3 page

Comment: OK. That is hard to track since you're inputing your chapters/sections and I don't know how they are formatted. It may have to do with a `\cleardoublepage` or something similar being inserted before a new chapter. But, as mentioned, hard to say without knowing the code. I'll try to have a look, but I may only be back at my desk late evening...

Comment: That's ok i appreciate the help. I have attached an image of how my chapters look if that helps

Comment: When I take the code snippet of your chapter 3 and put it in the main document, I get a result page with the correct footer (see my edit). Thus, from the code you provided here, I can't tell you exactly whats wrong.

Comment: I've added in my most recent preamble as I had to add a declaration too. Is there anything I could provide that would help resolve the issue? I just keep getting a blank page after the results page no matter what I do to resolve it.

Comment: I tried the same code on a different chapter and excluded that and I don't have a blank page. There is something specific with this chapter that causes that blank page. I even re did the chapter and found I had the same issue with the same code.

Comment: I think I fixed it, it was due to a figure being too long for the page and needed to move onto a new page. Thank you for you help though honestly very much appreciated!

Comment: Good to hear. If your problem is solved, you could accept the answer, so other users with similar problems may use the solution too :)